# Error 500 due to session

Tags: java, session

I'm getting below error on my page sometimes.

"ERROR: 500 - Server encountered exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed"

when I refresh the page it does'nt show again.
please let me know how can I resolve this??

Answer (score 1):

The error says "Cannot create a session after the response has been committed"

I suggest looking in your code and make sure that you are opening the session on line 1